# Task contínua execução mesmo após exceção

Tags: c#, task

O método **RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual** que se encontra dentro da Task abaixo está retornando uma exceção já tratada no próprio método, o problema é que a Task continua a execução da próxima linha **var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);** que depende do método **AbrirDataAtual** para ser executada, com isso, ela também lança uma exceção. Já tentei tratar dentro do método, colocar a task dentro de um Try/catch, mas nada funciona, sempre ocorre a exceção no método **ListaLinksDownlaod** sendo que não deveria nem chegar lá.

Como posso interromper a execução da task, tal como ocorre quando mandamos um CancellationToken, porém, desta vez, quando ocorrer qualquer exceção.

```
private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

        var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

        MethodInvoker action = delegate { pgbStatus.Maximum = links.Count(); };
        pgbStatus.BeginInvoke(action);

        return links;
    });
}
```

Comment: Você tá debugando certo pra entender o que realmente está acontecendo? e por que as exceptions não estão sendo tratadas? aparentemente a lógica do seu código não está fazendo muito sentido.

Comment: Sim, debuguei o código.. como disse, uma exceção esta sendo lençada no método  AbrirDataAtual(); esta exceção já esta devidamente tratada dentro do método, o problema é que mesmo com essa exceção lançada, o task ignora e continua a execução do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, seu problema é é: você quer parar a execução da thread se dentro de algum dos métodos houver uma excessão.
A solução para isso é: Seus métodos retornam um bool, que é setado como true caso você queira parar, e só executa o próximo método da thread caso essa variável seja false.

Exemplo:

```
private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        bool stop = false;

    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

    stop = RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

    if (!stop)
        stop = RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

    if (!stop)
    {
        var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

        MethodInvoker action = delegate { pgbStatus.Maximum = links.Count();};
        pgbStatus.BeginInvoke(action);

        return links;
    }     
});
}
```